# Is there an "of" syntax in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

```
newtype State s a = StateOf (s -> (s, a))

deState :: State s a -> (s -> (s, a))
deState (StateOf stf) = stf

instance Functor (State s) where
    -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> State s a -> State s b
    fmap f (StateOf stf) = StateOf (\s0 -> case stf s0 of (s1, a) -> (s1, f a))
```

In the last line

```
fmap f (StateOf stf) = StateOf (\s0 -> case stf s0 of (s1, a) -> (s1, f a))
```

The `of` syntax makes me confused. It seems not part of the `case` syntax.

Comment: But it is part of `case`. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Here is the list of all keywords: https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#case.2C_of

Comment: fully parenthesized, it's `case (stf s0) of { (s1, a) -> (s1, f a) }`. Might be a bit clearer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has to do with basic language syntax. Reading the docs would likely be a good place to start.

Comment: By the way, you can use record syntax for newtypes: `newtype State s a = StateOf {deState:: s -> (s, a)}`. Then you don't need to define `deState` separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @melpomene commented, the "of" is part of the case expression. See http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#case-expressions for further reference. Also the case expression is contained in a lambda expression which I would point you to http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#lambdas for reference. LYAH was and continues to be a great source (at least for me).